# How can I add an object that is segmented to the extracted mask? Using Segment Anything model?

Tags: image-segmentation

I want to add object that is segmented on the extracted mask.

```
mask_image = (mask * 255).astype(np.uint8)  
cv2.imwrite('mask.png', mask_image)
```